# Docker compose cannot find build path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run `docker-compose` but I'm thrown an "Build path does not exist..." error although as shown in the second last statement in the image below I am in the correct directory with the relevant files all inside.

[image: ock]

How do I fix this?

I'm using docker toolbox if it makes any difference.

Comment: It looks the file docker-compose.yml is recognized but can't be executed due to the errors in the file itself. Please post the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the same command, but from a CMD session, instead of a `git bash` session.

That way, a path like `C:\...` would be recognized by `docker compose`, from [Docker Toolbox for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/).